# javafx , how to show progress bar while printing into text area

Tags: java, batch-file, javafx, progress-bar

i am new in "programming thing , try to learn .
my "app" run bat test files , and all result printed in the textarea , it's working good.
but my goal now is to present  progress bar that will show the progress while printing into the text area.
how can i do it ?  I've read some guides and I tried somethings but it doesn't work for me

this is the method behind the button that run the bats files

```
public void RunTestScrip() throws IOException {

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);

    final InputStream stream = p.getInputStream();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                    
                    console.appendText("\n" + line);
                    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(RunTestScrip()); // dont know how to use it right in my code  

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // ignore
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Unless you know how much data you are going to receive in total, there is no way you can possibly update a progress bar (what would the progress be set to?). Do you have access to that information?

Comment: If you don't have data you can show a `ProgressIndicator` with value `-1` until the work is done so the user in not getting bored and breaks the keyboard :) .

Comment: DO yourself a favor and learn about try-with-resources. I'm pretty sure you're not using java 6 anymore, so you should be able to get rid of those finally blocks and declare and initialize the `reader` variable in a single step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think the script is able to update a javafx ProgressBar. The easiest way is to create your own rules about progress (probably based on the output you are currently appending to the console).

Here is a nice [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/progress.htm) on how to create a working Progressbar in javafx. Hopefully you are able ro figure out a way to update the progress accordingly.

Edit:

I added a small example of what can be found in the tutorial in case the provided link breaks.

```
// initialization of a progressBar with 'indeterminate progress'
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(-1.0D);

// to set the current state of a progress bar you simply do the following
pb.setProgress(current_progress);
```

Note that progress is a value between 0.0D and 1.0D (e.g. in percentage).
A value of -1.0D indicate that the progress is indeterminate.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Link-only answers are difficult to understand and are susceptible to become invalid if the website is down or not working. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can reproduce the most relevant portions of the link/blog you are referring to into this post itself.

Comment: thanks you,
i added if statement like this
`   if(line.contains("[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS"))
               {
                progressBar.setProgress(0.7);
               }`
and it's enough good for me